# Concatenate a String using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

i have a table:

```
-----------
-- Testy --
-----------
Dimension      Attribute      Value
----------     ----------     ------
PRODUCT        Name           T-Shirt
PRODUCT        Name           Pants
PRODUCT        Name           Sock
PRODUCT        Name           Wtf
STORE          Name           J-Store
STORE          Name           K-Store
STORE          City           Gotham
```

I was trying to use `FOR XML PATH` to make the concatenation of the values to have a result like this:

```
Dimension      Attribute      Value
----------     ----------     ------
PRODUCT        Name           in ('T-Shirt', 'Pants', 'Sock', 'Wtf')
STORE          Name           in ('J-Store', 'K-Store')      
STORE          City           in ('Gotham')
```

The table "Testy" is dynamic and can have different vales every day.

My query is the next:

```
select 
    [Dimension],
    [Attribute],
    [Value] = STUFF((
    SELECT N'', ' ,' + [AttributeValue] FROM Testy x
    WHERE [Dimension] = x.[Dimension] and [Attribute] = x.[Attribute]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
from Testy
group by [Dimension], [Attribute]
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? What's the output? Don't force people to create a table, insert data just to see what's wrong

Comment: BTW `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017. YOu don't use the XML technique to concatenate strings there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not qualifying your column names and it's giving preference to the inner query columns.

```
select 
    [Dimension],
    [Attribute],
    [Value] = STUFF((
        SELECT N'', ' ,' + [AttributeValue] 
        FROM Testy x
        WHERE t.[Dimension] = x.[Dimension] 
        and t.[Attribute] = x.[Attribute]
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
from Testy t
group by [Dimension], [Attribute]
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe that it's more that the column name was wrong on the sample data.

Comment: This fits perfect! Thx!